# Using differentials, estimate the amount of paint need to apply a coat of paint 2mm thick to a sphere with a radius of 30cm.

Tags: calculus

So first I use the surface area of a sphere which is $$ SA=4\pi r^2$$

but after that I have no idea what to do next because I shouldn't apply $\frac{d}{dx}$ until I have substituted in something for $r$ right?

Comment: Looks to me as if you're supposed to simplify $\frac 43 \pi (r+dr)^3 - \frac 43 \pi r^3$. And it simplifies to $4\pi r^2 dr$.

Comment: @IlikeSerena.  It does not simplify to that.  It is approximated by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V = 4/3×\pi r^3$
$dV/dr = 4\pi r^2$
Lower estimate for paint volume is 
$dV = 4\pi r^2 dr$

dr = 2mm, r = 30cm.  Calculate dV in cm$^3.$